# Unable to verify github pages dns using zero ssl

Tags: ssl, github-pages

I have tried all the ways to verify my domain for ssl certification from zero ssl but unable to do so. The txt file is successfully uploaded still clicking on its URL generates error

[verification failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IILSu.png)

[added cname](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BipJe.png)

[added html file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdUaX.png)

Answer (score 0):

It verify any file by sending request like `/abcd.txt`.
Therefore, do not keep the `.txt` file in any directory, instead keep it outside just like the `index.html` file.
And try again.